# Como criar uma extensão chrome que adiciona código na página

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Extensão Seguro ou não:

Preciso adicionar em uma página especifica (de preferência) ou em todas caso seja mais simples um determinado código.

Isso aqui funciona:

```
var meucode = 'alert("oi");';
var script = document.createElement('script');
var code = document.createTextNode('(function() {' + meucode + '})();');
script.appendChild(code);
(document.body || document.head).appendChild(script);
```

Ele da um alerta em todas as páginas que eu entro...

Pois bem, é possível adaptar isso para adicionar uma "imagem" no site que a pessoa entrar.

Comment: Você já tentou fazer isso e ver o que acontece?

Comment: Olá Marcelo, 
Neste site há um guia sobre como criar uma extensão para o chrome https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted, depois de ler esse é interessante abrir este https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview que mostra a arquitetura de uma extensão (quanto arquivos, nomenclatura e conteúdo básico eles precisam), por fim esse aqui https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index mostra um pouco das APIs disponíveis para o Javascript poder interagir com o navegador. Espero que isso ajude.